# Merge and rename [okhttp3] to [okhttp]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

OkHttp is now version 4.1.  It's API compatible with 3.14.  [okhttp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okhttp3) made sense at the time of the move from OkHttp 2, since they were different packages and not API compatible.

But at this point [okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okhttp) means OkHttp 3 or 4.

Can you please merge [okhttp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okhttp3) into [okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okhttp).  Ideally we would use [okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okhttp) exclusively going forward.

See project discussion here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5206

Comment: Before I merge [okhttp3] into [okhttp], can you please confirm these 106 [okhttp3] questions are suitable for merging as well? https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=&q=%5Bokhttp3%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%5Bjava%5D+-%5Bokhttp%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0

Comment: So, that would mean that older questions about OkHttp 2 and earlier would have the same tag as those version 3 and later. Seems kind of weird if they are not API compatible?

Comment: I’ll review those. But okhttp is already used for the new API.

Comment: Taking a look now, sorry for delays.

Comment: Just noticed the synonym was already added.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/okhttp/synonyms

Thanks!